# Get array value from variable

Tags: jquery, arrays

I'd like to get the value of an array depending on the index of the ul element. I'll try to explain myself:

```
var descgal0 = ["3456", "463", "6557", "5242"];
var descgal1 = ["gfdgfd" "gfgdfg", "gfdg", "gfdg"];
$("#gal-content-all section ul li img").click(function() {
   var index = $(this).parent().index();
   var indexul = $(this).parent().parent().parent().index();
});
```

The problem is

```
$("#gal-zoom h4").text(descgal0[index]); //WORKS!
 $("#gal-zoom h4").text("descgal"+indexul+[index]); //DOESN'T WORK :(
```

How could I get the array[li] value depending the ul I'm clicking on...??
Thank you!!!!

Comment: Thanks @Rads for the grammatic correction. English is not my native language ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use array of arrays since you have sequential indexes

```
var descgals = [
    ["3456", "463", "6557", "5242"],
    ["gfdgfd", "gfgdfg", "gfdg", "gfdg"]
];
$("#gal-content-all section ul li img").click(function () {
    var index = $(this).parent().index();
    var indexul = $(this).parent().parent().parent().index();
    $("#gal-zoom h4").text(descgals[indexul][index]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering your data model [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) seems like the only way :

```
$("#gal-zoom h4").text(descgal0[index]); //WORKS!
$("#gal-zoom h4").text(eval("descgal"+indexul+"["+ index + "]")); //SHOULD WORK :D
```

**But**, if you have control over the data model, you could go with something prettier than an `eval`, like this :

```
var descgal = [["3456", "463", "6557", "5242"],["gfdgfd" "gfgdfg", "gfdg", "gfdg"]];

$("#gal-zoom h4").text(descgal[indexul][index]);
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `eval`, try this:

```
$("#gal-zoom h4").text(eval("descgal" + indexul + "[" + index + "]"));
```

instead of this:

```
$("#gal-zoom h4").text("descgal"+indexul+[index]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
$("#gal-zoom h4").text(descgal0[index]); 
 arrName="descgal"+indexul;
$("#gal-zoom h4").text(arrName[index]);
```

Happy Coding:)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the solution was the Arun P Johny's option